# How do I fix blackscreen after connecting to xrdp on xfce4 (Kali Linux Rolling)?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, xfce4-terminal, xrdp, rdp

I installed `xrdp` on `xfce4` using `Kali Linux Rolling` distribution. I'm able to successfully connect to rdp service via `Microsoft Remote Desktop` from my Mac Pro.

I am unsure, how would I go about fixing blackscreen after I connect. This seems to temporarily resolve after i `stop` the xrdp service using `service xrdp stop` & then restarting it. However, after my xfce4 session goes back to login screen due to obvious sleep mode or 'lock-screen', it goes black again.

I tried:

1. customizing different scaling
2. using various screen resolutions
3. configured `.Xclients` to `startxfce4`
4. configured `.xsession` to `xfce4-session`

To no avail, I could get this working.

What would be a permanent solution likely to be approached?